# When will we see Gremlin support on the CosmosDB emulator?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Just downloaded the CosmosDB emulator and I was disappointed to find out that it doesn't.  Does anyone know if there are plans to add Gremlin support to the emulator?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not the right forum to ask this kind of things.

Answer (score 1):

We have plans to support all APIs supported by Cosmos DB on the cloud. Much of the work is done and I am eager to ship. API support will likely come before support in the Data Explorer (The Web UI).

Unfortunately, we don't yet have a release date.

Comment: So what is the workaround?  Gremlin server instead of the Cosmos DB emulator?